# How to union a vector with a pre-existing matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector, union

I have an example:

```
A = [1 5;2 6;3 7;4 8]

B = [1;2;3;4]
```

I wanna stack them in `C` as, with `C` formatted as:

```
C = [1 5 1; 2 6 2; 3 7 3; 4 8 4]
```

How to proceed? I have tried `vertcat`, `horzcat` with transposing, and `union`. None of them works.

Comment: How did `horzcat` not work? What is transpounding? What about just `C = [A, B]`?

Comment: Really? It's just `C = [A B]`.  I'm very skeptical that `horzcat` does not work. [Here's an online example of it working based on your inputs](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fUcFWIdpQwdTaSMHM2ljB3NpEwSLWWsEJLGxtZG1sbQLkOgO5GflFVcmJJRqOOgpOmtYKKZnFBRrOmtb//wMA).

Comment: `C = horzcat(A, B)` works fine for me...

Comment: dude im kinda starting from zero with matlab, maybe im doing something wrong. im gonna try ur tips, thanks

Comment: Don't worry. None of us are being hostile.  We are just in disbelief that `horzcat` doesn't work... because that means something is broken in MATLAB :P

Comment: I assume maybe the issue lies with "`horizcat` **with transposing**", i.e. maybe Ambro tried `horizcat(A, B.')` because they didn't realise `B` was already a column vector, causing a dimension mismatch?